# Flot time series, too many data points

Tags: flot

I've plotted win rate on a Flot chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/xR66k/

The x-axis displays the week number, but I don't want the points between these ticks (for example between week 37 and 38, and between week 41 and 42) – how can I remove these?

I'm creating the ticks with the following code:

```
var data = [[1382911200000,7.6805],[1382306400000,27.4607],[1381701600000,13.0376],[1381096800000,-26.3855],[1380492000000,-11.9624],[1379887200000,-5.018],[1379282400000,-11.0009],[1378677600000,50.5376],[1378072800000,0],[1377468000000,0]];

var ticks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ticks.push(data[i][0]);
}
```

Why does Flot plot extra data points?

Comment: This is a known issue with the threshold plugin: https://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=258

Comment: Note that this was migrated to issue #337 (https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/337) on Github, which is where we now track them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment this is a known limitation of the threshold plugin, so, let's work around it.  In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xR66k/2/), I've simply created two series one with just points and one with just lines.  The "just lines" will get threshold properly without the addition of point markers.

[image]

```
    data = [
        { label: 'Win Rate', data: data, points: {show:false} },
        { label: null, data: data, points: {show:true},  lines: {show:false} }
    ];
```

Comment: Nice! I had to add "hoverable: false" to the first series, but otherwise it's perfect. :-)